# "import _struct" error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I receive the following error when installing python 2.7.9 from these [instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python2.html):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

How do I make this error go away?

Comment: what happens when you run: sudo apt-get update?

Comment: Are you installing it on an LFS system?

Comment: The instructions you're following are intended for LFS. Following them on Ubuntu might conflict with the builtin packages.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the Python docs how to install the actual language